# System.load giving Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, environment-variables, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have an application which is using one native library libclient.so. which is dependent on another .so file.

I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH using command line on linux 32 bit system:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/usb:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

It is setting path as:

```
tushar@tushar-desktop:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/usb:/home/tushar/workspace/MinutiaeApp/resources:
```

But when I try to run my code I get **null** in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I think because of which I am getting Unsatisfied Link Error.

Here is my testing code:

```
String lib = "libclient.so";
String ld_lib_path = System.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
System.out.println("***LD_LIBRARY_PATH ***"+ ld_lib_path); // **GIVING NULL**
String[] paths = ld_lib_path.split(":");
for(int i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
    String p = paths[i];
    File x = new File(p, lib);
    System.out.println("***Path name *****" + i + " : "+ x.getAbsolutePath());
    if (x.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Exist");
       System.load(x.getAbsolutePath());
       break;
    }
 }
```

Actual Code:

```
System.load("/home/usb/libclient.so"); // **HERE I am getting Unsatisfied Link Error**
```

**UPDATE:**
I have set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the VM arguments and I am getting path name on running follwing line in my java code. So path is set.

```
 String ld = System.getProperty("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
```

Now the problem is that when I try to load the libgrfingerjava.so using `System.load("/home/arun/libgrfinger.so")` I still get Unsatisfied Link Error.

I tried loading some other .so file and I am able to do that. I don't know why I am getting error only on `libgrfingerjava.so`.

I am integrating [Griaule Finger SDK 2009](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/downloads) into my finger reading application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your program in the same shell?

You need to run your application in the same shell were you are setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it doesn't work if you have are modifying an environment in a "window console" and running your programm in Eclipse or another window.

UPDATE

If you are using Eclipse, in your menu, go to Project --> Properties --> Run/Debug Settings, then choose the configuration you're using and edit it, you will see this window:

[image]

Select the tab "Environment" and click on "New" you'll know what to do for the rest.

Comment: I am using eclipse. Could you please guide me to set it in the eclipse configuration?

Comment: Added help for Eclipse, try it out

Comment: I have tried setting in Environment configuration the path of library directory in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I don't know it still showing NULL.

Answer (score 1):

you should try to run this program from the same terminal from where you have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I am using eclipse. Could you please guide me to set it in the eclipse configuration?

Comment: in VM arguments try to set like the -DLD_LIBRARY_PATH=PATH\TO\THE FILE
and then try to get it like this 
      `System.getProperty("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");`

Thanks

Comment: please make sure there are no white spaces in your path if it is then put the complete path in double quotes. - Thanks

Comment: I have set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in VM arguments according to your suggestion. Now I am getting library path name on checking System.getProperty("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"). But still System.load(library) isn't loading the library in the application. What could be the issue?

Comment: With the assumption you are running this on Windows .. you have load it in the library path like this and it will expect a .dll file. (Give the absolute path of your DLL file)
   `-Djava.library.path=PATH\TO\DLL`

The JVM will search for your dll file in java.library.path system property. 

On the contrary if you are running in linux it will expect a .so file.

Comment: I am using linux 32 bit system. When I try to load some other .so file in same piece of code I am able to do that but when I load this .so file I hit Unsatisfied Link Error. ".so" I am trying to load is Griuale Biometrics Finger SDK 2009 libgrfingerjava.so. http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/downloads

Comment: @tech-idiot, thank you for mentioning the file extension issue. I had this exact problem due to some copying and temp file shenanigans and ensuring that the file had a ".dll" extension fixed everything.